# For loops in python with different variable names

Tags: python, loops

I'm new to Python and learning about loops. Can someone tell me why the name "Ringo" is printed four times here? The variable names are not the same so why would it even pick a name from the list.

```
for band_member in ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]:
    print (member)
```

The output is

```
Ringo
Ringo
Ringo
Ringo
```

Why is it even printing a name from the list?

Comment: `for A in B: print(C)` prints `C` 4 times and `A` 0 times.

Comment: You presumably set the variable `member` to `"Ringo"` in a previously executed line of code.

Comment: It's not picking a name from the list. `member` happens to be `'Ringo'` for unrelated reasons you haven't shown us.

Comment: member must have been previously defined to be equal to `'Ringo'`, which is why it is printing.

Comment: You guys are extremely sharp. I am using jupyter notebook and in my first effort I did use the variable member and then rewrote the variable name to band_member and I guess it retained that member value of "Ringo"

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone. You guys are really very sharp.

I am using jupyter notebook and in my first effort I did use the variable "member" and then rewrote the variable name to band_member and I guess it retained that member value of "Ringo" from the earlier usage.

I love it when there is a logical explanation that makes sense. Thanks all.

Comment: If I use a brand new session and use the same code as I posted it does give me an error that name 'member' is not defined. Which is exactly what I expected.

Comment: Yeah, you have to be careful about that with Jupyter. You can just restart the kernel to clear everything.

Answer (score 0):

It's picking a name "from the list" because you coincidentally set the value of `member` to a name from the list in code that you haven't shown us.

Your code actually looks like:

```
# ... blah blah

member = "Ringo"

# ... blah blah

for band_member in ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]:
    print (member)
```

So the `for` loop executes once for each value in the list, and you print `member` on each iteration.

This would do the same thing:

```
for band_member in [1,2,3,4]:
    print (member)
```

It's not picking from the list, it's just printing the variable you tell it to print.